# Как решить проблему с подтверждением регистрации?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Подключил плагин - Theme My Login и подключил в нем подтверждение регистрации пользователя через e-mail, но увы подтверждение не работает, тоесть приходит на почту письмо с ссылкой активации, но при переходе по ссылке, активация не происходит, в чем может быть проблема, заранее благодарен!

Comment: А по подробно можно? После перехода что на странице выдает? какую то ошибку? И еще посмотрите в базе или в админке генерированный урл совпадает с тем что пришло в письме ?

Comment: При переходе кидает на страницу входа но при попытке входа пишет, что почта не подтверждена, и в админке так же пишет, что пользователь не активирован. По поводу ссылки: ссылка из письма - сайт/login?action=activate&key=rLAsG3XR8vCj4DX0zRKL&login=anton. Код в базе: rLAsG3XR8vCj4DX0zRKL. Тоесть совпадают коды.

Answer (score 1):

> но при переходе по ссылке, активация не происходит, в чем может быть
>   проблема, заранее благодарен!

Наиболее частая проблема такого поведения - почтовый клиент обрезает ссылки вида `?action=rp&key=секретныйключ`.

Для того, чтобы убедиться в правильности отправки со стороны ВП можно  использовать плагины для логгирования почты. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/fx-email-log/

Другая причина - плагины якобы"безопастности", изменяющие стандартный адрес входа. При использовании TML они тем более не нужны - это можно изменять в его настройках.

Comment: В предыдущем комментарии отписал, вроде как не обрезает...

Comment: Скопировать ссылку - вставить в браузер. Убедиться что она правильная. Если будут проблемы - разбираться с плагинами "безопасности" и кеширования.

Comment: Скопировал ссылку, вставил, но ничего не поменялось, ссылка вида: сайт/login?action=activate&key=wvh9UoOAIf3FqIx6wFUw&login=anton

Comment: Вроде как нашел решение проблемы, с ссылки в предыдущем комментарии нужно убрать "login", и тогда оно будет кидать на главную страницу и при этом подтверждать! Но сразу же возникает вопрос, как изменить состав short-кода %activateurl%?

Comment: Те нечто изменяет урл.. Вот и нужно найти это "нечто" и дать по рукам :) %activateurl% - это не шорткод,а переменная. Не нужно её трогать.

Comment: Ну тогда даже не знаю в какую сторону смотреть что бы найти ТО, что меняет урл

Comment: Я ж говорил - др. плагины. Безопасности в первую очередь

Comment: Вроде нашел плагин который портит настроение - Rename wp-login.php Но теперь получается нельзя менять урл стандартной формы входа...

Comment: Вот видишь :) Я обновил ответ.